# RESTful endpoint for a third party call

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I have a resource `Payment` and a `PaymentController` that implements `index`, `show`, `store` and `update` methods.

- GET /payments => index
- GET /payments/id => show
- POST /payments  => store
- PUT /payments/id  => update

We use an external system to handle the payments and we need to query that system to get the updated status of the payment and now I need to implement a new method in the `PaymentController and a new endpoint that will trigger this call to the external system.

Initially I thought that this could be done in the `update` method, but this method allows to change details of the payment: amount, date, etc.

Am I breaking REST conventions if I create a new method like:

- PUT /payments/id/status  => status (which will call the external api, get the response and update the status of the payment in my database)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you are breaking any conventions. Although, I'd use a [job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes) which you can dispatch from your `update` method, or a [single action controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#single-action-controllers) to make it a bit more cleaner

Comment: Yes, the way I interact with the external api is via job. However, I'm not sure if I should use the same `update` method, unless I add some if statement to decide what kind of update the user wants to do (if he wants to simply change the some "local" value of the payment of it he really wants to "sync" the status of the payment with the external api